# Are Valarrays a specialized Templates?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, valarray

Can we be sure that `valarray` is a specialized class template ? and that's why it doesn't let implicite conversion happen ?

```
  std::valarray<int> values={1.0,2.0};

    for(int it: values ){

        std::cout<<it<<std::endl;
    }
```

> error: narrowing conversion of '1.1000000000000001e+0' from 'double' to 'int' [-Wnarrowing]

Comment: You are constructing `std::valarray<int>` using `std::initializer_list<double>` if that is your question

Comment: A `double` literal (like `1.0`) is not an `int`, and conversion from a `double` (literal or not) to an `int` involves narrowing.  That's what the `-Wnarrowing` warning will warn about.

Comment: I suspect what you wanted was `std::valarray<int> values={1, 2};` - that is, initialization using `int`egers, not `double`s.